# How to run Mapreduce from within a pig script

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I want to understand how to integrate calling a mapreduce job from within a pig script.

I referred to the link 
https://wiki.apache.org/pig/NativeMapReduce

But I am not sure how to do it as how it will understand which is my mapper or reducer code. The explanation is not very clear.

If someone can illustrate it with an example, it will be of great Help.

Thanks in Advance,
Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example from the [pig documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#mapreduce)

```
A = LOAD 'WordcountInput.txt';
B = MAPREDUCE 'wordcount.jar' STORE A INTO 'inputDir' LOAD 'outputDir' 
    AS (word:chararray, count: int) `org.myorg.WordCount inputDir outputDir`;
```

In the above example, pig will store input data from `A` into `inputDir` and load the job's output data from `outputDir`.

Also, there is a jar in HDFS called `wordcount.jar` in which there is a class called `org.myorg.WordCount` with a main class which takes care of setting mappers and reducers, input and output etc.

You could also call the mapreduce job via `hadoop jar mymr.jar org.myorg.WordCount inputDir outputDir`.

Comment: Hi @Fred , There is a Problem, I was able to execute the MR job, BUT the BIG BIG problem was that It is first copying the Input to the folder "inputDir" and Only after that , It is executing the MapReduce Job (here Wordcount.jar). So Copying Large Data would be time consuming and less efficient. Can You please suggest an Alternative to not Copy the data and still Use the MapReduce Code ??

Comment: I am not sure whether the STORE A INTO 'inputDir' is mandatory. If it isn't, just skip it. If it is, just copy some small dummy data to some location but read from the real/large input in your mapreduce program.

Comment: Thanks @Fred , It worked out for me, though I could not avoid the Store Function. Wondering If I have implemented my Own Pig Readers and read data via that Loader using Load Command, then This Technique might not work, If any alternative way of using Pig Loader Supplying data to Mapreduce can be found, out, then it will be a Bonus. Thanks for the help.!!

Answer (score 0):

By default pig will anticipate the map/reduce program. However hadoop comes with default mapper/reducer implementations; which is used by Pig - when map reduce class is not identified.

Further Pig uses the properties from Hadoop along with its specific properties for this. Try setting, below properties in pig script, it should be picked by Pig as well.

```
SET mapred.mapper.class="<fully qualified classname for mapper>"
SET mapred.reducer.class="<fully qualified classname for reducer>"
```

The same can be set using `-Dmapred.mapper.class` option as well. Comprehensive list is [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/JobConfFile)
Based on your hadoop installation, the properties could be as well:

```
mapreduce.map.class
mapreduce.reduce.class
```

Just FYI...

> hadoop.mapred has been deprecated. Versions before 0.20.1 used mapred.
>   Versions after that use mapreduce.

Moreover pig has its own set of properties, which can be viewed using command `pig -help properties`

```
e.g. in my pig installation, below are the properties:

The following properties are supported:
    Logging:
        verbose=true|false; default is false. This property is the same as -v switch
        brief=true|false; default is false. This property is the same as -b switch
        debug=OFF|ERROR|WARN|INFO|DEBUG; default is INFO. This property is the same as -d switch
        aggregate.warning=true|false; default is true. If true, prints count of warnings
            of each type rather than logging each warning.
    Performance tuning:
        pig.cachedbag.memusage=<mem fraction>; default is 0.2 (20% of all memory).
            Note that this memory is shared across all large bags used by the application.
        pig.skewedjoin.reduce.memusagea=<mem fraction>; default is 0.3 (30% of all memory).
            Specifies the fraction of heap available for the reducer to perform the join.
        pig.exec.nocombiner=true|false; default is false.
            Only disable combiner as a temporary workaround for problems.
        opt.multiquery=true|false; multiquery is on by default.
            Only disable multiquery as a temporary workaround for problems.
        opt.fetch=true|false; fetch is on by default.
            Scripts containing Filter, Foreach, Limit, Stream, and Union can be dumped without MR jobs.
        pig.tmpfilecompression=true|false; compression is off by default.
            Determines whether output of intermediate jobs is compressed.
        pig.tmpfilecompression.codec=lzo|gzip; default is gzip.
            Used in conjunction with pig.tmpfilecompression. Defines compression type.
        pig.noSplitCombination=true|false. Split combination is on by default.
            Determines if multiple small files are combined into a single map.
        pig.exec.mapPartAgg=true|false. Default is false.
            Determines if partial aggregation is done within map phase,
            before records are sent to combiner.
        pig.exec.mapPartAgg.minReduction=<min aggregation factor>. Default is 10.
            If the in-map partial aggregation does not reduce the output num records
            by this factor, it gets disabled.
    Miscellaneous:
        exectype=mapreduce|local; default is mapreduce. This property is the same as -x switch
        pig.additional.jars.uris=<comma seperated list of jars>. Used in place of register command.
        udf.import.list=<comma seperated list of imports>. Used to avoid package names in UDF.
        stop.on.failure=true|false; default is false. Set to true to terminate on the first error.
        pig.datetime.default.tz=<UTC time offset>. e.g. +08:00. Default is the default timezone of the host.
            Determines the timezone used to handle datetime datatype and UDFs. Additionally, any Hadoop property can be specified.
```